# Can you stop a process from running, using Fiddler2?

Tags: fiddler

I've just downloaded Fiddler 2 and installed it.  As its listing processing accessing the Internet/network, can I click on one of those processes and stop it from running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do that without writing FiddlerScript to extend the context menu or Tools menu with a new ContextAction or ToolsAction. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp